# Is there a working portable websocket to tcp gateway?

Tags: c, proxy, websocket, multiplatform

I have an app which works under linux/android/ios/osx/windows, and uses TCP/IP to communicate. I want to bundle a websocket to tcp gateway to the app so i can access it through a browser.

requirements:

- works on all those platforms (linux/android/ios/osx/windows)
- free license (LGPL, BSD, Apache or something similar)
- lightweight
- binary transfer

nice to haves:

- includes a static http server
- written in c

The closest thing i found is [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify), which works great when using python. But it is a big dependency. I can not easily bundle python to an android app for example.

There is a [c implementation of websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/other/websocket.c) , which seems to be too simple. It lacks binary support and static http server. And it fork()-s.

There is [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org/) which may be good, but i do not understand how it works, and implementing a gateway myself seems to be a bit much work. I do not know.

Maybe [nopoll](http://www.aspl.es/nopoll/), [libwebsock](https://github.com/payden/libwebsock), [wslay](https://tatsuhiro-t.github.io/wslay/index.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the right fit, since it's no-windows and no-TLS, but.... I wrote [facil.io](http://facil.io) for a Linux / BSD (inc. macOS) web server with websocket support (the Ruby server [iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) uses the library)... It works pretty well for me. If you write in add windows support to `libreact` and `libsock`, it would probably work on windows too....